# R programming: computation of biotic index?

Tags: r

I have a species abundance dataset (as .csv data format), which I want to write an automated r script to calculate biotic index (BI) for each sampling site. BI based on the presence-absence data. Here is my data (P indicates the presence of species): added the code format

```
df = data.frame(Species = c("Sp1", "Sp2","Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5", "SP6", "Sp7", "Sp8", "Sp9"), Site1 = c("P", NA, "P", "P", NA, "P", NA, "P", "P"), Site2 = c(NA, "P", "P", "P", "P", NA, "P", "P", NA), Site3 = c("P", "P", NA, "P", NA, NA, NA, NA, "P"), Site4 = c(NA, "P", NA, "P", "P", "P", NA, "P", NA), Site5 = c("P", "P", "P", NA, "P", NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

BI at each site can be calculated as = (sum of tolerance value of each species present in particular site/total number of species)*10

species tolerance values:

```
Sp1 =1.2, Sp2=1.1, Sp3=2.3, Sp4=4, Sp5 =2.5, Sp6=7, Sp7=2.7, Sp8=3.4,Sp9 =4.5, Sp10=5.5
```

Output table should like this:

```html
SiteName BI
Site1 37.3
Site2 26.7
Site3 27
Site4 36
Site5 17.8
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` i.e `dput(df)` and show expected output for the above example?

Comment: Hi Ronak, hope this is what you meant

Comment: So total number of species in your case is 9, right? Or do you want to count number of sites for each species ?

Comment: Yes, total number of species is 9, but not all the sites got all 9 species

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first create a reference dataframe with Species and their tolerance value.

```
ref_df <- data.frame(Species = paste0('Sp', 1:10), 
                     tolerance = c(1.2, 1.1, 2.3, 4, 2.5,7, 2.7, 3.4, 4.5, 5.5))
```

Get data in long format, join it with `ref_df`, calculate `sum` of `tolerance` value for each `Site` and divide it by total species * 10.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
 tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -Species, 
                     values_drop_na = TRUE, names_to = 'SiteName') %>%
 left_join(ref_df, by = 'Species') %>% 
  group_by(SiteName) %>%
  summarise(BI = sum(tolerance)/n_distinct(Species) * 10)
  #Or we can also divide by number of rows for each site.
  #summarise(BI = sum(tolerance)/n() * 10)


# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  SiteName    BI
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 Site1     37.3
#2 Site2     26.7
#3 Site3     27  
#4 Site4     36  
#5 Site5     17.8
```

Answer (score 0):

After reorganizing the datasets you can use `crossprod` to get weighted sums per Site which can be divided by the number of cases using `colSums` like:

```
x <- df[-1] == "P"
x[is.na(x)] <- FALSE
y <- ref_df$tolerance[match(df$Species, ref_df$Species)]

crossprod(x, y) / colSums(x) * 10
#          [,1]
#Site1 37.33333
#Site2 26.66667
#Site3 27.00000
#Site4 36.00000
#Site5 17.75000
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Species = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5", 
"Sp6", "Sp7", "Sp8", "Sp9"), Site1 = c("P", NA, "P", "P", NA, 
"P", NA, "P", "P"), Site2 = c(NA, "P", "P", "P", "P", NA, "P", 
"P", NA), Site3 = c("P", "P", NA, "P", NA, NA, NA, NA, "P"), 
    Site4 = c(NA, "P", NA, "P", "P", "P", NA, "P", NA), Site5 = c("P", 
    "P", "P", NA, "P", NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

ref_df <- structure(list(Species = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5", 
"Sp6", "Sp7", "Sp8", "Sp9", "Sp10"), tolerance = c(1.2, 1.1, 
2.3, 4, 2.5, 7, 2.7, 3.4, 4.5, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```